# Flutter Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled() isn't working as intended

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, geolocator

I'm trying to access a location in Flutter via the Geolocator package.
This works well but the location permission check has some sort of bug.

I check if the location service is enabled. Once it's accessed i check the users permission and then return location. This works quite as intended, but there is a problem with the first step.
I use

```
Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled()
```

to check if the location service is enabled. Unfortunately, this function just returns in some cases which leads to the whole function not returning, even though the location service is activated.

I already searched in different forums for answers and it seems to be a known problem although i didn't find a solution yet.

Attemps i tried to get access to GPS but failed:

- turning GPS off and on again
- closing and opening the app again
- inserted

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in AndroidManifest

- hot restart in IDE

I could just access the location if i re-run debugging, but not each time...

Does anybody have a clue how to get this built-in function to work as intended?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.
I used the permission_handler package and replaced

```
Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled()
```

with

```
final hasPermission = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus.isEnabled;
```